# How to get a service to work in a lifecycle event listener

Tags: php, symfony, event-listener

I have a service that I use on different places in my project. In my Controllers it works perfectly.

I need it in a prePersist lifecycle event listener, but calling the service there doesn't want to work. When I try it I get the following error;

> Attempted to call method "get" on class
>   "Xx\Xxx\XxxxBundle\Lib\Yyyy\OrderUserListener".

I think that I understand that I have to inject my service in my event listener, but i don't understand how to do it.

This is how the `OrderUserListener` and `OrderLogger` services looks like in the service.yml file respectively;

```
bss.pmod.current_user_id:
    class: Xx\Xxx\XxxxBundle\Lib\Yyyy\OrderUserListener
    calls:
    - [ setServiceContainer, [@service_container] ]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }

bss.pmod.order_logger:
    class: Xx\Xxx\XxxxBundle\Lib\Yyyy\OrderLogger
    arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@security.token_storage" ]
```

And this is my OrderLogger function I want to inject in my service;

```
class OrderLogger {

    private $em;
    private $tokenStorage;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param EntityManager $em
     * @param TokenStorage $securityTokenStorage
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, TokenStorage $securityTokenStorage)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->tokenStorage = $securityTokenStorage;
    }

    /**
     * Log an order action.
     *
     * @param string $text
     */
    public function log($order, $action)
    {
        $logRecord = new PmodLog();
        if (is_object($this->tokenStorage->getToken())) {
            $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
            if (is_object($user)) {
                $logRecord->setUser($user);
            }
        }
        $logRecord->setOrder($order);
        $logRecord->setAction($action);
        $logRecord->setTime(new \DateTime());

        $this->em->persist($logRecord);
        $this->em->flush();
    }

}
```

My event listener looks like this;

```
class OrderUserListener
{

    /**
     * Service container
     * @var type 
     */
    private $serviceContainer;

    /**
     * Performs tasks before destruction
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $order = $args->getEntity();

        if ($order instanceof PmodOrder) {
            $user = $this->serviceContainer->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

            if ($user) {
                $order->setCreatedBy($user);
                $order->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
                $order->setDepartment($user->getDepartment());
                $order->setStatus(PmodOrder::STATUS_AWAITING_APPROVAL);

                //$this->get('bss.pmod.order_logger')->log($order, 'Order Created');      // This is then clearly wrong.
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the sales order exporter object
     * @param type $serviceContainer
     */
    public function setServiceContainer($serviceContainer)
    {
        $this->serviceContainer = $serviceContainer;
    }
}
```

If somebody can explain to me by showing how to do it with my sample, I'll really appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Can you provide your `OrderUserListener` definition? Like you did for `OrderLogger`

Comment: You mean the service definition in my service.yml file for the `OrderUserListener`?

Comment: Yes, seems you need to add your `bss.pmod.order_logger` as an argument to it.

Comment: I've updated my question. Look at the part where I mention the service.yml file with the two services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, looks like you're mixing `ContainerAwareInterface` (now deprecated in favour of `ContainerAwareTrait`) with Symfony's `Controller` base class. `ContainerAwareInterface` is designed to distinguish classes that need a service container injected, and controllers get it injected automatically. Since it appears that this line works:

```
$user = $this->serviceContainer->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

, it looks that the container is injected properly.

The `get()` method that you're trying to call from your service actually reminds me of [`Controller`'s `get()` method](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L411). But your class is not a descendant of `Controller`, and by no means it actually is a controller, as far as I can tell.

What you should do instead of calling `get()` here is call the container:

```
$logger = $this->serviceContainer->get('bss.pmod.order_logger')->log($order, 'Order Created');
```

However, ContainerAware services are usually considered a bad practice. You could instead inject the services directly through the constructor:

```
# Service definition
bss.pmod.current_user_id:
    class: Xx\Xxx\XxxxBundle\Lib\Yyyy\OrderUserListener
    arguments:
        - "@security.token_storage"
        - "@bss.pmod.order_logger"
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }

class OrderUserListener
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    private $logger;

    public function __construct($tokenStorage, $logger)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    // ...

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        // ...

        // Here you can call the injected services:
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

        $this->logger->log($order, 'Created');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is on the right track but will results in a cyclic dependency error.  The doctrine entity manager service is actually dependent on it's entity listeners.  In your example, the entity listener is in turn dependent on the logger which itself is dependent on the entity manager.  Boom! Injecting the container is one way to get around this.  A better way is to extract the entity manager from $args and pass it to the logger.

Comment: Thanks for the answer kix, I will try it. But what do you mean @Cerad? Can you maybe elaborate more to help me get it to work on the right way? Or is the line `$logger = $this->serviceContainer->get('bss.pmod.order_logger')->log($order, 'Order Created');` mentioned by kix enough? Because then it is the same as the down voted answer below, and that leads to another error. I guess I will then just work on that error and ask a new question...

Comment: I would have expected the downvoted answer to at least get you past the posted error message.  Anytime you are trying to update the database ($em->flush()) from a listener you may have problems.  But see what happens.

Comment: At a minimum you probably want to remove the flush statement from your logger.

Comment: This answer is correct. It worked in the end. My mentioned error in my previous comment on July 29 was something totally different.

Answer (score -1):

Change `$this->get('bss.pmod.order_logger')->log($order, 'Order Created');` to `$this->serviceContainer->get('bss.pmod.order_logger')->log($order, 'Order Created');`

Comment: If you put -1 then explain the reason

Comment: I'm not the one down voting, but I remember that I actually tried it that way. I got another error doing that. I can't check it right now, but I will come back to you on Monday morning.